# IE does NOT work correctly with RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, internet-explorer, mod-rewrite

I am about to start using RewriteRule on my website and it is working great so far except for Internet Explorer (IE).

The issue is that IE does not show the images and cannot recognize CSS. All other Browsers work fine!
Obviously it is a path issue, but I tried with

- RewriteBase
- `<BASE>` tag in the html
  and no success, it is still the same.

More information I can provide is that when I use "/" at the end of the new URL (exmpl: www.domain.com/new-rewrite-rule-url/ ) the images canNOT be displayed in IE only, other browsers works fine with or without "/".

If I remove this "/" (example: www.domain.com/new-rewrite-rule-url ) it is all good and images and everything is OK even with IE.

Web Server is Apache.

Comment: Have you looked at the exact URLs and HTTP status code in Internet Explorer developer tools?

Comment: Redirect without `/` or add `<base href` in your html code